# How do I tag the gender of a noun with Spacy?

Tags: spacy

I would like to tag the gender of nouns using Spacy; specifically in my case, German.

I am not sure which Spacy pipeline has information about noun gender, for example, the Tagger or the Lemmatizer?

Answer (score 1):

Different languages have different grammatical features, so you can look at the specific [language model](https://spacy.io/usage/models) of a language to determine what pipelines it has.

For [German](https://spacy.io/models/de), we can see under “Label Scheme” that the “morphologizer” pipeline has tags including “gender”.

[Here](https://spacy.io/api/morphologizer), it shows that the morphologizer assigns the attribute “morph” to each Token.

“morph” is respectively of type “[MorphAnalysis](https://spacy.io/api/morphology#morphanalysis)”.

There are different ways to access the morphological annotation from a MorphAnalysis object.

The simplest is to use the “.get” method, by passing the name of the category you want:

```
Token.morph.get(“gender”)
```

which returns a list of strings in case that category has multiple values.

You can also return the MorphAnalysis as a dictionary with `to_dict()`, as a string with `str(Token.morph)`, or iterate over `Token.morph` with a loop, which returns each attribute-value pair as strings.